# REST API design - handling inter-field dependencies

Tags: api, rest, api-design

I have a resource called `User` which has the following fields: `id`, `last_name`, `date_of_birth`, `organization_id`, and `employee_number`.

I want to define a search end-point that allows people to retrieve users that satisfy some conditions. For e.g. people whose `last_name` is "John", and who are born after a certain date. For this, I have can have a generic `/user/search` end-point that takes these conditions as `GET` parameters.

However, there are certain business rules for certain queries. For e.g. `employee_number` cannot be queried unless accompanied by the `organization_id` field. I find mentioning this in the documentation ugly. How should I enforce this in a more elegant fashion?

One idea I have is to have a `/user/employee_number/:number` end-point that takes `organization_id` as a mandatory `GET` param. But this does not seem "REST"ful. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First, note that URIs don't determine "RESTfulness". They are arbitrary identifiers. Having said that, we usually want nice URIs.

Here is an non-exhaustive list of options to consider.

**Option 1. Hiearchical.** One option: if every employee is dependent on an org then you could have

```
/organization/:org/employee/:number
```

Clean enough, but employees/users are important resources, so you may not want them existing as second-level resources. Fair enough.

A more serious objection is that this ties the user to a particular org. In real life people move around from org to org, and we don't usually think of this entailing an identity change. In effect, with this approach, the resource is the user's *employment* within a given organization, as opposed to being the user him/herself.

**Option 2. Matrix params.** If you want /employee or /user to be top-level, then another option is so-called [matrix params](http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/MatrixURIs.html):

```
/user;org=:org;number=:number
```

These aren't official, but since Tim Berners-Lee came up with the idea, people treat it as a semi-official pronouncement. (I think they look ugly but that's a purely aesthetic judgment; it doesn't have anything to do with RESTfulness.)

This has the same problem as option #1 regarding employees moving around.

**Option 3. Database ID.** Third option:

```
/user/:id
```

where `:id` is just some database identifier. Document the search as requiring org + employee number as required to guarantee uniqueness. It doesn't have to be "ugly"—for example the [HAL spec](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) has a nice documentation scheme based on CURIEs.

Again the URI is just an arbitrary identifier so using the DB ID is fine. Basically people would have to query the employee by org, employee number, etc., but the employee's `self` link would return a URI containing a database ID.

Nice and clean, but clients can't directly construct the URIs, which incidentally is in line with the [HATEOAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS)/hypermedia philosophy underlying REST: small number of entry points into the API, and client navigates around (i.e. effects app state transitions) using links embedded in the resources.

Moreover this allows the user to move from org to org without having to assume a new identity.